# Interpretation of H. P. Lovecraft's racist poem

Tags: meaning-in-context

While I'm researching an America's influential gothic/horror genre writer, H. P. Lovecraft, and his racism, I found his poem called On the Creation of N*****s. I hope someone helps me to clarify some parts.

> When, long ago, the gods created Earth
>
> In Jove's fair image Man was shaped at birth.
>
> The beasts **for lesser parts** were next designed;
>
> Yet were they too remote from humankind.
>
> To fill the gap, and join **the rest** to Man,
>
> **Th'Olympian host** conceiv'd a clever plan.
>
> A beast they wrought, in semi-human figure,
>
> Filled it with vice, and called the thing a N*****.

1. What does bolded 'for lesser parts' mean?
2. Does bolded 'the rest' refer to all creatures except beasts?
3. Does bolded 'th'Olympian host' refer to gods of the Olympus?

Answer (score 2):

When, long ago, the gods created Earth

In Jove's[1] fair image Man was shaped at birth.

The beasts for **less important roles** *[in the life of the planet]* were next designed;

Yet were they too remote from humankind.

To fill the gap, and join (= **provide a link between**) *the rest *[of the life forms]* **and** Man[kind],

Th'Olympian[2] host *[an army; a crowd]* conceiv'd a clever plan.

[1] Julian. Jupiter, or **Jove**: In **Roman** mythology, the king of the gods and equivalent to **Zeus** in **Greek** mythology https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jupiter_(mythology)

[2] Lovecraft has made a mistake. Jove was a **Roman** god. It was Zeus, with the other **Greek** gods, who lived on the sacred Mount Olympus in Greece - hence "Olympian". ("Olympian" can mean "of the abode of the gods" but here, it is simply confusing.)